# Accepting JSON format, parsing him and having endpoints to accessing the data (Django)

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

Hello I want to ask how can I create models and API in Django that accepts JSON format, parsing it and then access it in some of the endpoints. I want to have [POST] endpoint `/import` which will accept the data and parse them, [GET] `/detail/<name_of_the_model>` will show list of records from the JSON file based on the name of the model and finally `/detail/<name_of_the_model>/<id>` which shows all the data for the exact record from the JSON file. I think I can manage things with the models/modelForms but I can't figure out how to implement it with JSON. Thanks for any help.

PS: There are like 8 different variables with attributes (don't know how is it called in JSON) and I'm not sure if I'm doing it right if I create model for each of the variables. That's why I think that import the JSON is such a big thing but don't know how to do it.

EDIT: I've installed REST Framework to Django. Maybe that could be the way, but still have no idea how to do it properly. Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement a REST API and web interface in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940073/implement-a-rest-api-and-web-interface-in-django)

Comment: Maybe it could be it... But I don't know why Django don't want to accept that rest_framework app and I don't know why. When I implement it and do something like `from rest_framework import something` it causes an error. And when I look at the line itself I see that rest_framework is underlined so I don't know if I am doing something wrong with implementation of the model itself or what.

Comment: Did you install DRF? See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation

Comment: Yes I installed it exactly from this site.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the answer here on the StackOverflow... I needed to change the interpreter to virtual env. Thanks for help anyway... I hope REST Framework will help me out